# Prove that if $E[X]$ is finite, then $E[|X|]$ is finite

Tags: probability-theory

So far I have been able to show that since $E[|X|]$ is finite, then $E[X]$ is finite but I'm having trouble showing the reverse, that if $E[X]$ is finite, then $E[|X|]$ is finite. I know that $E[X]=\int xf(x)\,dx$ over the support of $x$. Any direction would be helpful.

Comment: Hint: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}=\int_{-\infty}^0+\int_0^\infty$

Comment: For a measure space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$ (for simplicity, let $\mu$ be a nonnegative measure), the equivalence of $\int_{\Omega} \lvert f\rvert\,\mathrm{d}\mu < \infty$ and $\left\lvert \int_{\Omega} f\,\mathrm{d}\mu\right\rvert < \infty$ is true for all measurable functions $f : \Omega\to \mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 3):

You normally define expectation in this way: Start with $X$ being a non-negative random variable. Then, define $E[X] = \int X dP$ which is always well defined (but possibly infinite).

Then, you let $X^+ = \max(X,0)$ and $X^- = \max(-X,0)$. Both $X^+$ and $X^-$ are non-negative random variables, so you can say $E[X^+]$ and $E[X^-]$ always exist. Note $X = X^+ - X^-$.

We define $E[X] = E[X^+] - E[X^-]$ when at least one of $E[X^+],E[X^-]$ is finite. Note that $E[X]$ is finite if and only if both $E[X^+],E[X^-]$ are finite (by the way its defined). Then, note $|X| = X^+ + X^-$, so if $E[X]$ is finite, $E[|X|] = E[X^+] + E[X^-]$, both which are finite so $E[|X|]$ is finite.

Answer (score 0):

If $EX$ is finite (and hence is defined) then $EX^+<\infty$ and $EX^{-}<\infty$. But 
$$
E|X|=EX^++EX^{-}.
$$